# Frame size of UIView when loaded from Nib?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, interface-builder, xib

I am loading a UIView from a .xib file like this:

```
static func loadFromNib() -> CardView {
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "CardView", bundle: nil)
    return nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! CardView
}
```

When loaded the view has the exact frame size as set in "Frame Rectangle" of the Size Inspector in the Interface Builder.

Is this guaranteed? I need this size to be exact, because subview constraints are specific and will not fit if the view has the wrong size [*], but I didn't find any mention of this in Apple's docs.

[*] = Reason: I am rendering the view to an UIImage so I can display it in and UIImageView later on. It shows the image of a membership card and name and membership number need to be in the right place with the correct font size on all devices..

Answer (score 4):

Set any UIView subclass as owner of xib, then load xib as subview of this view and set autoresizing mask.

This is how I use it:

```
extension UIView {
    func loadXibView(with xibFrame: CGRect) -> UIView {
        let className = String(describing: type(of: self))
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: className, bundle: bundle)
        guard let xibView = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as? UIView else {
            return UIView()
        }
        xibView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        xibView.frame = xibFrame
        return xibView
    }
}
```

`xibView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]` sets size of view properly.

Then just use it any UIView subclass in initialization:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    addSubview(loadXibView(with: bounds))
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    addSubview(loadXibView(with: bounds))
}
```

Comment: Thanks Vasilii. I was just wondering about whether the frame I set in the Interface Builder is guaranteed at runtime, but you also set xibView.frame explicitly, so I guess you don't use it or trust it either. ;) Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Create a custom class for your UIView:

```
class CardView: UIView {

override init(frame: CGrect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    let xibView = UINib(nibName: "CardView", bundle: nil).instantiate(withOwner: nil, options:nil)[0] as! UIView
    self.addSubview(xibView)
    }   

require init?(coder: aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }  
}
```

and then call if from the class you'll be implementing it in with the frame size you need or otherwise it will default to the size that is set in your interface builder:

```
// MyViewController

var cardView: CardView?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.cardView = CardView()
    self.cardView.frame.size = CGSize(size here)
    self.cardView.frame.origin = CGPoint(point here)
    self.view.addSubview(self.cardView!)

}
```

Comment: So basically you also set the frame manually. Alright, I guess it does not hurt to set the frame in code, just to make sure the xib-size is not guaranteed.